# Dataframe apply to return dataframe, and append it to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

dataframe question..
I use "apply" on dataframe to do some function on each row of the dataframe.

the function supposed to return another dataframe.

I want to append each dataframe the function return to another dataframe.

example:

```
def func():
  # some dataframe creation
  return dataframe # can be 2 dim dataframe

my_df.apply(func, axis=1) # my_df is big dataframe with a lot of rows
```

In the end, I want dataframe to hold all the results.

Thanks

Comment: Did you find a solution to this??

Answer (score 0):

just assign the return to be a dataframe:

```
new_df = my_df.apply(func)
```

Comment: not working as I want. it returns dataframes of dataframes ( if it makes sense...) I think its because the returning dataframe is 2x15